# What do 'ea' and 'fcs' mean for build version?

Tags: build, versioning

What do 'ea' and 'fcs' abbreviations mean in a build versioning? I suppose 'ea' stands for 'early access' but I could be wrong. I don't have any idea what is 'fcs'.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Afcs - 9th hit for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally `fcs` is  `First customer shipment`

Ie the first one to escape the labs and  be given the mere mortals :)